# Getting Test Accuracy for model.predict_generator

Tags: python, keras

I am calling `model.predict_generator()` method for predictions on Test data-set. My question is how can I retrieve test accuracy ? Following is my code line:

```
predictions = model.predict_generator(test_images, steps=3,  verbose=0)
```

Where `test_iamges` in the parameter of `predict_generator` function has batch data retrieved from local disk by calling `ImageDataGenerator`

Any guidance will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a corresponding function `model.evaluate_generator` that will give the loss, acc etc on your test set *but not the predictions*. Have a look at the model [documentation](https://keras.io/models/model/), ex:

```
loss, acc = model.evaluate_generator(test_images, steps=3, verbose=0)
```

> **Returns:** Scalar test loss (if the model has a single output and no metrics) or list of scalars (if the model has multiple outputs and/or metrics).